# How synchronized block achieve synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

In Java if a method is qualified by `synchronized` keyword, it ensures that this method will be accessed by a single thread at any time, by manipulating objects `monitor` such that when a thread enters a synchronized method it locks `monitor`, so that all other threads know it is already locked by another thread.

My Question here is how does synchronized block achieve synchronization, What I mean is that there is no `monitor` associated with this synchronized block so what indication it uses to determine if this block is already in execution? I am lost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each object has an implicit lock associated with it. When entering a synchronized block, the process must acquire the object's lock before continuing. The lock is returned upon exiting the synchronized block.

```
public class SomeClass {
   private Object mutex = new Object();
   public static synchronized void method1() {
      // static methods aquire the class level lock for SomeClass 
   }
   public synchronized void method2() {
      // aquire the lock associated with 'this' instance (of SomeClass)
   }
   public void method3() {
      synchronized (mutex) {
         // aquire the lock of the mutex object
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: is that implicit lock refer to object's monitor which is used by synchronized method or its something different?

Comment: I think we are referring to the same thing, I'm calling it a lock whilst you're calling it a monitor.

Comment: Please Note!  This can't be said enough times!  The three methods in Lance's example synchronize on three different locks.  One of the biggest newbie mistakes is to think that two methods can not interfere with one another just because both are synchronized.  It's only true when they are both synchronized on the same lock.